# extract specific filenames from a zip without extracting it

Tags: bash, solaris, zip

Listing the contents of the zip file as below:

```
wladmin@solarishost:/tmp$ unzip -l -q /tmp/package-391.zip | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -n '3,$p' | grep -v '^$'
myapp/src/stage/bras.war
myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/bras.war
myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/perf/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/prod/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/qa/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/uat/deployfiles/acid.properties
```

From the above I wish to create a delete file list by getting all filename that have `deployfile` and not having `DEV` which I'm able to do using the below.

```
wladmin@solarishost:/tmp$ unzip -l -q /tmp/package-391.zip | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -n '3,$p' | grep -v '^$' | grep deployfiles | grep -v -i DEV
myapp-configuration/src/config/perf/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/prod/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/qa/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/uat/deployfiles/acid.properties
```

from whatever is left i.e

```
myapp/src/stage/bras.war
myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/bras.war
myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/deployfiles/acid.properties
```

From the leftover output, I wish to get any filenames that appear more than once i.e

```
myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/bras.war
```

and add it to the delete file list

Final desired output:

```
myapp-configuration/src/config/perf/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/prod/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/qa/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/uat/deployfiles/acid.properties
myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/bras.war
```

End goal is I will use the final desired output list to delete those files from the zip and reconstruct the zip with the below 2 files only:

```
myapp/src/stage/bras.war
myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/deployfiles/acid.properties
```

Kindly suggest.

```
wladmin@solarishost:/tmp$ uname -a

SunOS solarishost 5.11 11.4.62.151.3 sun4v sparc sun4v non-global-zone
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit of a convoluted specification. If I understand correctly, you want the list of archive members whose path does not contain `deployfiles` (unless they also contain `dev` case insensitively), and ignore subsequent files that have the same basename.

So:

```
zipinfo -1 file.zip | nawk -F/ '
  (! /deployfiles/ || tolower($0) ~ /dev/) && !seen[$NF]++'
```

`zipinfo -l` being [one of the ways to get only the list of zip archive member paths](/q/128303).